# Rails production nginx+unicorn, все запросы к приложению проходят с ip 127.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Как решить данную проблему?
После того как я подключил unicorn на production server у меня в логах видно, что все запросы к приложению проходят с ip 127.0.0.1 и даже Devise регистрирует current_sign_in_ip как 127.0.0.1

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-22 09:09:35 +0100
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-22 09:09:39 +0100
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    upstream app_production {
      server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app_production.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name app.exemple.com;
      root /home/deployer/app_production/current/public;
      rails_env production;
      client_max_body_size 50M;

      location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
      }

      try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app_production;
      location @app_production {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwared-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_production;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nginx перезапускал? Unicorn? конфиги к базам верно прописаны?

Comment: Да перезапускал, даже ребутил сервак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отталкиваться от следующей конфигурации

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;

    upstream app_production {
      server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app_production.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name app.exemple.com;
      root /home/deployer/app_production/current/public;
      rails_env production;
      client_max_body_size 50M;

      location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
      }

      try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app_production;
      location @app_production {
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   CLIENT_IP         $remote_addr;

        proxy_pass http://app_production;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: и снова ничего, похоже нужно закрывать вопрос, так как в интернете описано ровно то же что описываете Вы, но мне почему-то не помогает(((

Comment: Я нашел чистый сервер с такой же проблемой, в логах unicorn 127.0.0.1 от nginx, добавил proxy_set_header-ы из приведенного выше конфига, перезагрузил nginx и у меня стал передаваться IP-адрес клиента. Посмотрите логи nginx - там точно адрес клиента, может у него тоже проблемы с получением IP-адреса? Не может перед ним обратный прокси стоять, который не корректно предает IP-адрес клиента вашему nginx?

Comment: лог nginx `81.25.228.220 - - [22/Mar/2016:14:19:02 +0100] "GET /api/v1/airports HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://app.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: лог unicorn `127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2016:14:22:28 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.0362`

Comment: лог rails `I, [2016-03-22T14:24:28.139162 #1312]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-22 14:24:28 +0100`

Comment: потушил сервер и запустил снова, заработало
Хотя до этого рестартил сервак, рестартил nginx, unicorn